# Use PHP variable in HTML but in a PHP file

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm trying to have the value of a PHP variable there's my code:
...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
$var = $row['num'];
echo $var;
echo '<tr><td align="left">' . 
$row['id'] . '</td><td align="left">' . 
$row['num'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
$row['used'] . '</td><td align="left">' . 
$row['temps'] . '</td><td align="left">' . 
$row['prix'] . '</td><td align="left">' . 
$row['date'] . '</td><td align="left"> .
<p>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value=$var />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
</p>
</form>';

echo '</tr>';
}
```

i'm trying to put the value of $var but when i do this code there's an error

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\Site test\php\mysql_getInfo.php on line 39

For information my code is getting the database and putting on a website, I'm trying to add button to delete from the database.

Comment: sidenote: `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`.

Comment: How can i do that so ?

Comment: Your error has a line number in it... you should be able to narrow it down with that. At the very least, include the line numbers to assist someone willing to help you.

Comment: Variables in single quotes aren't variables. The `.` between the `td` and `p` is not concatenating.

Comment: the error is here :<input type="text" name="name" value=$var />

Comment: This is your actual code? Nothing here would cause the error you've included. https://3v4l.org/puNk5

Comment: Like this: `'<input type="text" name="name" value="' .$var. '" />';`

Comment: Don't put `like` code, post the actual code so we can actually help. I'd guess you missed a `.` on one of the sides of the `$var`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i recommend you to echo every line and also extracting ur $var:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
$var = $row['num'];
echo $var;
echo '<tr><td align="left">';
echo $row['id'] . '</td><td align="left">';
echo $row['num'] . '</td><td align="left">';
echo $row['used'] . '</td><td align="left">'; 
echo $row['temps'] . '</td><td align="left">';
echo $row['prix'] . '</td><td align="left">'; 
echo $row['date'] . '</td><td align="left">';
echo '<p>';
echo '<form action="delete.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value='.$var.' />';
echo '</p>';

echo '<p>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '</form>';

echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Echo every line why????

Comment: Your code is not showing the error anymore but it is not filling the <input type="text" name="name" value=$var /> by the value of $var :) sry if my questions are stupid i'm learning php :)

Comment: @Dagon personally i like to be organised and i am lazy to concentrate string because i am scared to have errors concentrating the strings

Comment: You don't need to concatenate